# How to share a 3G connection through Ubuntu to Windows?

Tags: linux, networking, windows-7, ubuntu

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 10.10 installed and internet connection through a 3G modem.

I set up a wireless network on Ubuntu, set up its IP to `192.168.0.1`, netmask `255.255.255.0` and gateway `192.168.0.1`, and then connected to this WiFi.

On Windows 7, I set up IPv4 settings, entered the IP address for computer `192.168.0.2`, netmask `255.255.255.0`, gateway `192.168.0.1`, the same as Ubuntu. Then Windows 7 recognized the network, but there was no internet access.

How is this possible?

`ifconfig` results:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:22:c3:8a:6e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:46 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:592030 (592.0 KB)  TX bytes:592030 (592.0 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.139.93.32  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:198 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:49502 (49.5 KB)  TX bytes:25607 (25.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:4c:e5:8f:19:cf  
          inet6 addr: fe80::924c:e5ff:fe8f:19cf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:507 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4083 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:45203 (45.2 KB)  TX bytes:316853 (316.8 KB
```

Comment: This is off-topic for stackoverflow. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: What specifically did you set up? How does it look like in network manager, or even better: Show us the output of `ifconfig`. Gateway `1.1.1.1` does not make any sense at all – where did you get this info?

Comment: now when i find it from windows 7 it connects but says that IPv4 Connectivity: No Network access

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, since 10.10, try using **Network Manager**. It had a nice "share connection" dialog, where you could start a wifi hotspot IIRC. Also, you will need **Firestarter**, since that does the connection sharing. At least, this is how I shared my 3G connection. (But seriously, the other way around would be much more convenient with Connectify/VirtualRouter on Windows, and the Ubuntu guest.)

Answer (score 0):

Question: How is it possible that the ubuntu machine does not automagically acts as a router.
Answer: You have to tell it to.

Use Shikis's answer and use the Network Manager: [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)

You should not use a WiFi access point, as it will try to be the default route unless you can configure it not to.

So make sure you are using ad-hoc networking.